# "Mon Mar 14 00:04:26 +0000 2016" to "yyyy-mm-dd" format in Hive?

Tags: hive

I have the following `"Mon Mar 14 00:04:26 +0000 2016"` and I want to convert it into `"yyyy-mm-dd"` format in Hive. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT from_unixtime( unix_timestamp('Mon Mar 14 00:04:26 +0000 2016', 
'EEE MMM d H:mm:ss +0000 yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

*`2016-03-14`*